# Java Spring MVC web app crashes after deploy on railway.app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I try to deploy Java Spring MVC web app which works fine on my localhost with Tomcat, but when deploy on railway.app, it crashes or find nothing when try to use any controller path/address. My webapp configuration files:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>pl.krzysztofskul</groupId>
  <artifactId>sensit5</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>sensit5</name>
  <description>A simple sensit5.</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <maven-compiler-pluging.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-pluging.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- E-MAIL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<!--        <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-pluging.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.1.0</version>
             <configuration>
               <archive>
                 <manifest>
                   <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                   <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                   <mainClass>pl.krzysztofskul.sensit5.App</mainClass>
                 </manifest>
               </archive>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

App.class

```
package pl.krzysztofskul.sensit5;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class App extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World sensit5!" );
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() { return null; }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter };
    }
    
}
```

AppConfig.class

```
package pl.krzysztofskul.sensit5;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleContextResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "pl.krzysztofskul.sensit5")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean(name="localeResolver")
    public LocaleContextResolver getLocaleContextResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pl","PL"));
        return localeResolver;
    }
  
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry handlerRegistry) {
        handlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    
}
```

HomePageController.class

```
package pl.krzysztofskul.sensit5;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @GetMapping({"/home", "/"})
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test/home")
    @ResponseBody
    public String testHome() {
        return "test home sensit5";
    }
    
}
```

Gihub: https://github.com/krzysztofskul/sensit5.git
Railway: https://sensit5-test.up.railway.app

Comment: Railway url is invaild , pls provide one another accessable url

Comment: I generated this url on railway's dashboard. Any url I create doesn't work. But when I use  SprongBOOT configuration in my pom.xml everything works fine.